# Who is (or was) Susan Williams?

Tags: history, lego-group

I've heard the name "Susan Williams" associated with LEGO products, especially in the 1980s. Who is / was she?

Comment: Related: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/563/132

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> **Q: All of the LEGO catalogs are signed by Susan Williams. Is she a real person?**
>
> A: No...Susan Williams is the personifcation of all those
>   helpful Consumer Affairs people who work at LEGO. As for whether or
>   not there ever was a Susan Williams at LEGO, we're not sure.

http://www.lugnet.com/pause/legoqa.html

Comment: Today I learned that Susan Williams is not a real person.

Comment: @BoltClock For some reason, this makes me sad.

Comment: @LarsTech I feel like a legend just died.